# Add matched elements to a new element while keeping those not matching as they are

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to process an XML file, where I know that some elements with a particular attribute should be children of a new element. Other siblings of those elements that not match should remain there the same. An example will be better.

The tokens I want to match have attribute id='t_15' and id='t_16'.

This is the input XML:

```
<text>
  <div id="d_1">
    <p id="p_1">
      <s id="s_1">
        <token id="t_13" lemma="colleague" pos="NN">Colleagues</token>
        <token id="t_14" lemma="," pos=",">,</token>
        <token id="t_15" lemma="we" pos="PP">we</token>
        <token id="t_16" lemma="now" pos="RB">now</token>
        <token id="t_17" lemma="come" pos="VVP">come</token>
        <token id="t_18" lemma="to" pos="TO">to</token>
        <token id="t_19" lemma="catch-the-eye" pos="NN">catch-the-eye</token>
        <token id="t_20" lemma="." pos="SENT">.</token>
      </s>
      <s id="s_2">
        <token id="t_21" lemma="these" pos="DT">These</token>
        <token id="t_22" lemma="be" pos="VBP">are</token>
        <token id="t_23" lemma="the" pos="DT">the</token>
        <token id="t_24" lemma="name" pos="NNS">names</token>
        <token id="t_25" lemma="I" pos="PP">I</token>
        <token id="t_26" lemma="will" pos="MD">will</token>
        <token id="t_27" lemma="call" pos="VV">call</token>
        <token id="t_28" lemma="out" pos="RP">out</token>
        <token id="t_29" lemma="." pos="SENT">.</token>
      </s>
    </p>
  </div>
</text>
```

This is the output I would like to get:

```
<text>
  <div id="d_1">
    <p id="p_1">
      <s id="s_1">
        <token id="t_13" lemma="colleague" pos="NN">Colleagues</token>
        <token id="t_14" lemma="," pos=",">,</token>
        <e>
          <token id="t_15" lemma="we" pos="PP">we</token>
          <token id="t_16" lemma="now" pos="RB">now</token>
        </e>
        <token id="t_17" lemma="come" pos="VVP">come</token>
        <token id="t_18" lemma="to" pos="TO">to</token>
        <token id="t_19" lemma="catch-the-eye" pos="NN">catch-the-eye</token>
        <token id="t_20" lemma="." pos="SENT">.</token>
      </s>
      <s id="s_2">
        <token id="t_21" lemma="these" pos="DT">These</token>
        <token id="t_22" lemma="be" pos="VBP">are</token>
        <token id="t_23" lemma="the" pos="DT">the</token>
        <token id="t_24" lemma="name" pos="NNS">names</token>
        <token id="t_25" lemma="I" pos="PP">I</token>
        <token id="t_26" lemma="will" pos="MD">will</token>
        <token id="t_27" lemma="call" pos="VV">call</token>
        <token id="t_28" lemma="out" pos="RP">out</token>
        <token id="t_29" lemma="." pos="SENT">.</token>
      </s>
    </p>
  </div>
</text>
```

This is the stylesheet that I am using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"></xsl:output>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="dif_tok">
        <dif_tok>t_15</dif_tok>
        <dif_tok>t_16</dif_tok>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="s">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
            <e>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*[@id = $dif_tok/dif_tok]"></xsl:copy-of>
            </e>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is, finally the result that I am getting:

```
<text>
  <div id="d_1">
    <p id="p_1">
      <s id="s_1"><e><token id="t_15" lemma="we" pos="PP">we</token><token id="t_16" lemma="now" pos="RB">now</token></e></s>
      <s id="s_2"><e/></s>
    </p>
  </div>
</text>
```

Comment: Sorry, although in the original post I used a XSLT 2.0 declaration (I've just edited it). I would prefer a XSLT 1.0 solution. I want to integrate it in a python script using lxml, which only supports XSLT 1.0

Comment: I've tried Ian's solution, it is exactly what I am looking for, but it is XSLT 2.0. Now, I cannot see his proposal anymore but it was very good.

Comment: Next time you ask something make sure you use the right version. This is quite annoying I have to say.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: I know, I apologize for that. It was my first question here, and I've just started combining XSLT with lxml for python. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

> some elements with a particular attribute should be children of a new element

Write a separate template to match the `token` element you are interested in.

```
<xsl:template match="token[@id ='t_15']">
```

Inside the template, generate an `e` element and take advantage of the behaviour of `apply-templates` to fill it with the tokens where `@id = t_15 and t_16`. Then, let the identity transform do all the rest.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="token[@id ='t_15']">
      <e>
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::token[1]"/>
      </e>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
  <div id="d_1">
      <p id="p_1">
         <s id="s_1">
            <token id="t_13" lemma="colleague" pos="NN">Colleagues</token>
            <token id="t_14" lemma="," pos=",">,</token>
            <e>
               <token id="t_15" lemma="we" pos="PP">we</token>
               <token id="t_16" lemma="now" pos="RB">now</token>
            </e>
            <token id="t_16" lemma="now" pos="RB">now</token>
            <token id="t_17" lemma="come" pos="VVP">come</token>
            <token id="t_18" lemma="to" pos="TO">to</token>
            <token id="t_19" lemma="catch-the-eye" pos="NN">catch-the-eye</token>
            <token id="t_20" lemma="." pos="SENT">.</token>
         </s>
         <s id="s_2">
            <token id="t_21" lemma="these" pos="DT">These</token>
            <token id="t_22" lemma="be" pos="VBP">are</token>
            <token id="t_23" lemma="the" pos="DT">the</token>
            <token id="t_24" lemma="name" pos="NNS">names</token>
            <token id="t_25" lemma="I" pos="PP">I</token>
            <token id="t_26" lemma="will" pos="MD">will</token>
            <token id="t_27" lemma="call" pos="VV">call</token>
            <token id="t_28" lemma="out" pos="RP">out</token>
            <token id="t_29" lemma="." pos="SENT">.</token>
         </s>
      </p>
  </div>
</text>
```

---

Your attempted solution uses a variable. This is a good approach, too:

```
<xsl:variable name="start" select="'t_15'"/>

<xsl:template match="token[@id=$start]">
  <e>
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::token[1]"/>
  </e>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias! Just to make it more flexible, let me ask you something: the spans of tokens that I would like to append to element `<e>` may have any length, say 1 token or n number of tokens. How would you do it? I can pass to the stylesheet a parameter with the first token id and the length of tokens to be processed, or the id of the last token. Say, that instead of only t_15 and t_16 I wanted to process only t_15, or t_15, t_16, t_17. Best!

Comment: `<token id="t_16" lemma="now" pos="RB">now</token>` appeared twice in the output.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen: good point. This is a not so good side effect.

Comment: I agree with @Joel. It might be best to use `xsl:for-each-group` as Ian suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified slightly the stylesheet made by Mathias. See below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="start" select="'t_15'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="middle" select="'t_16'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="end" select="'t_17'"/>

    <xsl:template match="token[@id =$start]">
        <e>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::token[@id=$middle]" mode="group"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::token[@id=$end]" mode="group"/>
        </e>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="token[@id =$middle]|token[@id =$end]" mode="group">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="token[@id =$middle]|token[@id =$end]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: since I wrote this answer the question has been changed to require XSLT 1.0 rather than 2.0, but I'll leave the answer here for reference.

---

Since you're in XSLT 2.0 this is an ideal case for the `group-adjacent` mechanism of `for-each-group`.  Assuming you have the identity template as before, then how about

```
<xsl:variable name="tokensToGroup" select="('t_15', 't_16')" />

<xsl:template match="s">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:for-each-group select="token" group-adjacent="@id = $tokensToGroup">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
          <e><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" /></e>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Adjacent tokens whose ids match `$tokensToGroup` will be gathered into a single group with a `current-grouping-key()` value of boolean `true`, other tokens will be gathered into groups with a key of `false` - we only wrap an `<e>...</e>` around the ones with the `true` key.

If instead of a list of all the IDs to group, you just have the IDs of the first and last tokens, then you can use the same mechanism but with a different grouping key definition

```
<xsl:param name="first" select="'t_15'" />
<xsl:param name="last" select="'t_17'" />

<xsl:for-each-group select="token"
   group-adjacent="( (. | preceding-sibling::token)[@id = $first] and
                     (. | following-sibling::token)[@id = $last] )">
```

Here the `true` key value is for elements that are at-or-after the `$firstToken` *and* at-or-before the `$lastToken`.  This might be a bit more efficient with a key, assuming the processor doesn't already optimize it, e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="tokenById" match="token" use="@id" />

<xsl:variable name="firstToken" select="key('tokenById', $first)" />
<xsl:variable name="lastToken" select="key('tokenById', $last)" />

<xsl:for-each-group select="token"
   group-adjacent="( (. is $firstToken or . &gt;&gt; $firstToken) and
                     (. is $lastToken or . &lt;&lt; $lastToken) )">
```